# How to setup domain name to ipaddress/webapp1/webpage?

Tags: tomcat, dns

I purchased a domain name (www.domainname.com) in godaddy.
 I have a tomcat server deployed working application at path http://174.xxx.x.xx/WebApp1/webhome

When I create an AList in godaddy that accepts only ip address. So,after setting up AList, my application is reachable only by typing: www.domainname.com/WebApp1/webhome.
If I type just www.domainname.com it doesnt work.

I just want to type www.domainname.com and bringup my application instead of typing www.domainname.com/WebApp1/webhome..
1) should I do any config change in tomcat server ?
2) Or should I just use forward instead of AList in godaddy?

thanks

Comment: This belongs on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed it by 
1)renaming WebApp1.war to ROOT.war and deployed again.
2) creating AList record to ip address.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

check your public html folder, you can create an index.html, with the following code

`<meta HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=www.domainname.com/WebApp1/webhome">`

in the header.

or you can change `web.xml` under tomcat conf folder

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>./yourpath/yourpath/webaindex.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>`
```